# How do I check a particular status code in apex?

Tags: apex

Salesforce has the following error code: NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS.  How can I use getStatusCode() and see if the error is equal to that constant?  I'm not sure of the syntax to reference the error code:

```
Approval.Processsubmitrequest req = 
            new Approval.Processsubmitrequest();
try {
    req.setObjectId(newUser.Id);
    Approval.ProcessResult result  = Approval.process(req);
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (result.getErrors()[0] == Error.ALREADY_IN_PROCESS) {
        // handle error error
    } 
}
```

This code does not compile.  Can anyone help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things:

1. `result` is delclared within the try block and would be out of scope in the catch block.
   You could either declare `Approval.ProcessResult result  = null;` before the try block and then first check if it is null in the catch block. Alternatively, move the status check inside the try block.
2. I don't see a `getStatusCode()` instance method on [Approval.ProcessResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ProcessResult.htm). Did you intend to use `getErrors()` instead?

As best as I can tell the NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS error is a DmlException, so you will probably want to deal with the exception rather than the ProcessResult.

---

The [Exception class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex230/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm#dml_email_exception_methods) has a getDmlStatusCode() method that returns an integer, but is has been deprecated. Instead you should use the Exception.getDmlType() method and the [StatusCode Enum](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_enums.htm).

```
} catch (DmlException ex) {
    System.assertEquals(StatusCode.ALREADY_IN_PROCESS,ex.getDmlType(0));
}
```

Comment: I placed the declaration outside the try block.  There are a number of possible errors I'm trying to trap, this was just an example to get the syntax correct for trapping the error.  Please see the revised code -- different error.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JimH. You can use the `getDmlType(i)` method on the DMLException to get the specific StatusCode.

Comment: StatusCode enum http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm#statuscode Link is broken. I didn't find a replacement.

Comment: @SamKamensky I've updated to the current document link. It isn't super useful though as it now refers to the WSDL for the full list. That will tell you what the codes are, but not what they imply.

Comment: Ah thanks! 
True, it doesn't give explanations. But going to https://na88.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/metadata at least shows you a list of all possibilities.